# Material tailwind react Navbar component having extra padding around it

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

[navbar have extra few pixel of padding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNFbH.png) When I use Tailwind CSS Navbar - React from material tailwind react library (https://www.material-tailwind.com/docs/react/navbar#navbar) ,there is extra padding around it. I keep other files remain unchanged (using typescript) as when I initiate the app.

topnav.tsx:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Navbar,
  Typography,
} from "@material-tailwind/react";
 
export function CustomNavbar() {
  const [openNav, setOpenNav] = React.useState(false);
 
  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener(
      "resize",
      () => window.innerWidth >= 960 && setOpenNav(false)
    );
  }, []);
 
  const navList = (
    <ul className="mb-4 mt-2 flex flex-col gap-2 lg:mb-0 lg:mt-0 lg:flex-row lg:items-center lg:gap-6">
      <Typography
        as="li"
        variant="small"
        color="blue-gray"
        className="p-1 font-normal"
      >
        <a href="#" className="flex items-center">
          Pages
        </a>
      </Typography>
      <Typography
        as="li"
        variant="small"
        color="blue-gray"
        className="p-1 font-normal"
      >
        <a href="#" className="flex items-center">
          Account
        </a>
      </Typography>
      <Typography
        as="li"
        variant="small"
        color="blue-gray"
        className="p-1 font-normal"
      >
        <a href="#" className="flex items-center">
          Blocks
        </a>
      </Typography>
      <Typography
        as="li"
        variant="small"
        color="blue-gray"
        className="p-1 font-normal"
      >
        <a href="#" className="flex items-center">
          Docs
        </a>
      </Typography>
    </ul>
  );
  
  return (
    <div className="">
      <Navbar className="sticky top-0 z-10 h-max max-w-full rounded-none bg-blue-gray-600">
        <div className="flex items-center justify-between text-blue-gray-900">
          <Typography
            as="a"
            href="#"
            className="mr-4 cursor-pointer py-1.5 font-medium"
          >
            Material Tailwind
          </Typography>
           <div className="flex items-center gap-4">
            <div className="mr-4 hidden lg:block">{navList}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Navbar>

    </div>
  );
}
```

todo.tsx: (where I call my navbar)

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import '../styles/checkbox.css'; 
import TodoListComponent from '../components/todo-list';
import todoList from '../data/mock-data/todolist.json';
import Sidebar from '../components/sidebar';
import '../styles/sidebar.css';
import { usePagePadding } from './function/pagePadding';
import { CustomNavbar } from '../components/topnav';

// redux
import type { RootState } from '../redux/store';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { onSidebarChange } from '../redux/sidebar';
import { onMousePositionChange } from '../redux/mousePosition';

function Todo() {
  // redux
  const pagePadding = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.pagePadding.value);
  const sidebar = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.sidebar.value);
  const mousePositionX = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.mousePosition.x);
  const mousePositionY = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.mousePosition.y);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const toggleSidebar = () => {
    dispatch(onSidebarChange(!sidebar));
  };

  usePagePadding();

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleMouseMove = (event: MouseEvent) => {
      dispatch(onMousePositionChange({ x: event.clientX, y: event.clientY }));
    };

    window.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener(
        'mousemove',
        handleMouseMove
      );
    };
  }, []);

  const pageContentStyle = {
    paddingLeft: `${pagePadding}rem`,
    paddingRight: `${pagePadding}rem`,
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <CustomNavbar />
      <div className={`page-container ${sidebar ? 'ml-80' : ''}`}>
        {/* <button onClick={toggleSidebar}>Toggle</button> */}
        {/* {sidebar && <Sidebar />} */}
        <div className='pt-padding-heading1' style={pageContentStyle}>
          <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold">
            Task
          </h1>
          <div className='pt-padding-component-medium'></div>
          {todoList['todolist'].map((title, index) => (
            <TodoListComponent key={index} title={title} index={index}/>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Todo;
```

App.tsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import Todo from './pages/todo';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className='font-body'>
      <Todo />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

index.tsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from './redux/store';

// @material-tailwind/react
import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-tailwind/react";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ThemeProvider>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

extra info: I'm using edge to view.
Any suggestions?

Please tell me which setting causing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<Navbar>` component has a `1px` white border around it by default. You can customize component styles by [pass in your own theme object to `<ThemeProvider>`](https://www.material-tailwind.com/docs/react/theming). For example, to remove the border completely:

```
const theme = {
  navbar: {
    styles: {
      base: {
        navbar: {
          blurred: {
            borderWidth: '',
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
…
<ThemeProvider value={theme}>
```

Please find [a full working example on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-jripxx?file=src%2Fmain.jsx&terminal=dev).